# Going from one webpage to the next trough hyperlinks with VBS

Tags: vbscript

i'm writing a script to go trough 600+ hyperlinks and get information from them, but here is the catch i never wrote a vbs script before

so i got my very basic "go to site X script", and once there i want to follow a hyperlink on that page, PROBLEM i can't use the string adress of the link becaus later i want to go to site Y (same site but i'm looking up a different word ) Y will have the same button for the hyperlink as X but the string behind it will be different

anyone has an idea on how to make the script to go to the link for X and later for Y (so without using the string of the hyperlink

THANKS

```
>Option Explicit
>Dim objCHR
>Set objCHR = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
>objCHR.Navigate "http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?locus=YGR084C"
>objCHR.visible = true
```

Comment: The category of things that does this is called a "crawler" or "web crawler".  There may be tools out there that do what you want, and your solution is a matter of finding them and learning how to use them.  Or, it could be that you have specific requirements that recommend writing a script. What you want does not seem very complicated but your description is not so clear, so I think people will have difficulty providing you with direct advice. To encourage answers, You may want to elaborate a little on the concept and provide some examples or illustrations.

Comment: Is there a reason the script must use VBScript?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

i wonder why you use vbscript if this is your first program, there are languages that are fat better in doing such things (eg Ruby) and that have masses of libraries that do webcrawling etc.
Plenty examples here at stackoverflow. I post here a Ruby example as another answer.

Can't follow you with the X Y links but here is the way to load the contents of the page, you have to extract then the info you need by i simple instr and mid or with a regular expression.
If you let us know what exactly you want to achieve i can help you further.

```
Set objCHR = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
objCHR.Navigate "http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?locus=YGR084C" 
objCHR.visible = true 
Do while not objCHR.ReadyState = 4 'wait till the page is loaded
  Wscript.Sleep(100)
Loop
Wscript.Echo objCHR.Document.body.InnerHTML 'show entire contents as HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to learn a scripting language then learn Ruby or Python.
Here a simple Ruby script that shows all links on a page, this one use nokogiri as library, you could also use mechanize.

```
require 'nokogiri' 
require 'open-uri' 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?locus=YGR084C" ).read) 
hrefs = doc.css("a").map do |link| 
  if (href = link.attr("href")) && !href.empty? 
    URI::join(url, href) 
  end 
end.compact.uniq 
STDOUT.puts(hrefs.join("\n"))
```